# Failed run shell which contains nohup command

Tags: linux, expect, nohup

I have two machines, I call it A and B, and I write a shell in A, which should run B's script, in machine A script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# testA.sh

source ~/.bash_profile
expect <<EOF
spawn ssh B@ip "sh /another/path/testB.sh"
expect "*password:"
send "pwd\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

In machine B script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# testB.sh
source ~/.bash_profile

nohup python ./test.py >2&1 &
```

I run testA.sh in A, but the `test.py` which is in the same directory as the `testB.sh` does not run in backend in B. And I can run the `testB.sh` successfully in B. How can I deal with it?

Comment: What does `test.py` do? How do you detect that it is not run? Where is `test.py` located? What is user B's home directory? What is user B's `PATH` after running `~/.bash_profile`? Can you successfully run `sh /another/path/testB.sh` as user B on the remote machine when the current directory is user B's home directory? Note that when you run `sh /another/path/testB.sh` the script will be run by `sh` not by `/bin/bash`.

Comment: please post a [repro]